# Screen artifacts on brand new computer fixed by driver update - should I worry?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, visual-artifacts

I'm currently bench testing a new computer I've just built which started displaying slowly flickering white screen artifacts at the very end of the Windows setup process, and which continued in Windows itself, until I updated the graphics card driver from the Windows Basic Graphics Device Driver to the nVidia driver. After I did this the artifacts went away. Further, there are no artifacts in the UEFI, none whilst running MemTest86 and none (anymore) in FurMark.

[image: Computer monitor with screen artifacts]

The thing is, I don't know if this is merely an early warning of bad things to come, and if I should be sending the graphics card back now while I still can, or whether since the driver update has fixed it there's nothing to worry about. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly does look like a driver issue, when the Windows operating system initializes, it downloads compatible drivers from Windows Update, the drivers are generic so they are not tailored to individual devices, they are not "best match" drivers by design to be compatible to more devices, such a driver can cause the problem you described here.

You said your computer is brand new, and after you updated the GPU driver the issue is fixed, based on this information I am 99.99% sure it was caused by driver issues, so don't worry, your computer is fine.